# textscan in MATLAB: read NULL value as NaN

Tags: matlab, file-io, nan, csv, textscan

I have a .txt file with the following data:

#### sampleF.txt --> (tab delimited)

```
MSFT    200    100
APPL    10    NULL
AMZN    20    40
```

I need to read this data using `textscan`. I am facing a problem while reading the `NULL` data. Using `treatasempty` param, I can read it as 0. But I want to read it as `NaN`. Please help!  Thanks!

```
fName = '.....\sampleF.txt'
[fid, message] = fopen(fName) ;
if fid < 0, disp(message), else
    datatxt = textscan(fid, '%q %d %d', 'Delimiter', '\t','treatAsEmpty','NULL');
    datatxt = [ datatxt {1} num2cell(datatxt {2}) num2cell(datatxt {3})] ;
    fclose(fid) ; 
end

%datatxt = { 'MSFT' [200] [100] ; 'AAPL' [10] [NaN] ; 'AMZN' [20] [40] }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the fact that the type `int32` does not support NaN values. Instead read the numbers as doubles. ie:

```
data = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f', 'Delimiter','\t', ...
           'treatAsEmpty','NULL', 'EmptyValue',NaN);
```